# refresh button to update xml bounded listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, refresh

I have a listbox which is bounded to xml datasource.
I want to create a button that refreshes the list box.

listbox1.refresh is not working.

Thaks

```
private void LoadXML()
{
    presets.Clear();
    if(System.IO.File.Exists(GetXMLFileName()))
    {
        XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(GetXMLFileName());
        XElement xMain = xDoc.Element("Main");
        foreach(var xPreset in xMain.Elements())
        {
            Preset preset = new Preset(xPreset);
            presets.Add(preset);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < maxPresets; i++)
            presets.Add(new Preset() { Id = i });
    }
    listBox1.Items.Clear();
    listBox1.DataSource = presets;
    listBox1.DisplayMember = "name";
}
```

Comment: You are not supposed to use both Items and DataSource together.  If your listbox is bounded properly, changing the DataSource will automatically 'refresh' it.  If however you are changing 'presets', your presets needs to be an observablecolleciton.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this line:

```
listBox1.DataSource = presets;
```

Although you are setting `DataSource`, after the first call to `LoadXML()`, you are setting it to the same value it already had.  Since the collection reference is the same, the assignment is effectively a no-op: the underlying data source didn't change, so the list box won't refresh.  The simplest fix would be to reset `DataSource` to `null` before setting it to `presets`.  Ideally, though, you should simply bind the data source to an `ObservableCollection`, or some other collection that supports change notifications.

Also, as @user2880486 noted, you should not use both `Items` and `DataSource`; they are designed to be mutually exclusive.  Use one or the other, but not both.

Comment: Thanks, But when i try "listBox1.DataSource = null;" iget: "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection."